# Can't autoclick icon link within a frame for a webpage VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a vba code to autoclick icon link after logged in.  I'm stuck with the vba code I wrote below and when I run the vba macro no responses.  I believe the icon link is within a frame for a webpage.  Please help thanks

I've tried right clicking on the icon link to check for the frame url address, and navigate to that webpage once logged in however it automatically redirects to another page which I don't want.

URL address (target webpage with the icon link): "https://trading.poems.com.hk/poems2/poems.asp?func=view"

Auto Redirected webpage: "https://trading.poems.com.hk/poems2/loginaction.asp"

The icon link html code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="StockPop = window.open ('http://www.poems.com.hk/stockSummary/stockSummary.asp?                                            iKey=2755766c747a25535353574373b375a375c05','StockAnalytics','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,left=0,top=0,width=1250,height=700,toolbar=0')"><img src="images/Corner/EN/Company.png" border=0 title="Stock Analytics "></a>
```

My VBA code:

```
Sub open3()
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://trading.poems.com.hk/poems2/poems.asp?func=view"


Do Until ie.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop


For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
If InStr(ele.innerHTML, "images/Corner/EN/Company.png") > 0 Then
ele.Click


Exit For
End If
Next

End Sub
```

The frames of the webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Phillip Securities (HK)-?????? (?????????)</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/phillip.ico">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5"></head>

     <frameset cols="*, 100%" border=0 frameborder=0 framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0>
<frame src="Poems2/BrowserChecking.asp" name="ChkBrowser">
<frame src="Poems2/Poems.asp" name="login" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 marginheight=0   marginwidth=0>
      </frameset><noframes></noframes>
     </html>
```

Parts of the HTML source code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transtitional//EN"
 http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" />
   <title>??????-?????????</title>
    </head>
     <link href="css/phillip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" >document.domain="poems.com.hk"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu_Execution_EN.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/ddsmoothmenu.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ddsmoothmenu.init({

mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
//customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myclose = false;

function ConfirmClose()
{
    frameURL = (parent.DetailFrame.location.href).toUpperCase()
    //alert(frameURL + "////   " + frameURL.indexOf("PPSHK.COM"))
    if (frameURL.indexOf("PPSHK") > 0)
    {

        if (event.clientY < 0)
        {
            event.returnValue = '???????????, ?????????\n????!';
            //setTimeout('myclose=false',10000);
            //myclose=true;
        }
    }
}

function parentExists() {
    return (parent.location == window.location) ? false : true;
}

if(!parentExists())
    document.location = "../index2.htm"



function checkKeyCode(evt)
{
    var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
    if(event.keyCode==116)
    {
        location.reload(true);
        return false
    }
}
document.onkeydown=checkKeyCode;
</script>
<body onUnload="CloseAllPop()">
<script>
    var EFuturePop
    var StockPop
    var USStockPop
    var SGStockPop
    var JPStockPop
    var SAStockPop
    var SOptionPop
    var SNOptionPop
    var StockGTCPop
    var BullionPop
    var FxBannerPop

    var FoFuturePop
    var ForexPop
    var FoOptionsPop

    var ForexResponse
    var FoFutureResponse
    var FoOptionsResponse

    function CloseAllPop(){
        if(EFuturePop != null){
            EFuturePop.close()
        }
        if(StockPop != null){
            StockPop.close()
        }
        if(USStockPop != null){
            USStockPop.close()
        }
        if(SGStockPop != null){
            SGStockPop.close()
        }
        if(JPStockPop != null){
            JPStockPop.close()
        }
        if(SAStockPop != null){
            SAStockPop.close()
        }
        if(SOptionPop != null){
            SOptionPop.close()
        }
        if(SNOptionPop != null){
            SNOptionPop.close()
        }
        if(StockGTCPop != null){
            StockGTCPop.close()
        }
        if(BullionPop != null){
            BullionPop.close()
        }
//      if(FxBannerPop != null){
//          FxBannerPop.close()
//      }
        if(FoFuturePop != null){
            FoFuturePop.close()
        }
        if(ForexPop != null){
            ForexPop.close()
        }
        if (FoOptionsPop != null) {
            FoOptionsPop.close()
        }
    }

    function forexClose(ans){
        ForexResponse = ans;
    }

    function foFutureClose(ans){
        FoFutureResponse = ans;
    }

    function foOptionsClose(ans) {
        FoOptionsResponse = ans;
    }

    function DisclaimerClose(type,ans){
        if (type == "Forex"){
            ForexResponse = ans;
        }
        else if (type == "FoFuture"){
            FoFutureResponse = ans;
        }
        else if (type == "FoOptions") {
            FoOptionsResponse = ans;
        }
    }

    function changeDetailFrame(link) {
        $('#DetailFrame').attr('src',link);
    }

    function CheckStockGTCPop(){
        if(StockGTCPop != null){
            parent.DetailFrame.location.href = "NoPopup/ZH/TradeStock_GTC.asp"
        }
        else{
            StockGTCPop = window.open('StockDisclaimer_GTC.asp','HKStockGTC','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
        }
    }

    function CheckForexPop(){
        if (ForexResponse=="A"){
            if (ForexPop.closed) {
                ForexPop = window.open('Forex/asp/menu/100kforex_fr.asp','Forex','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
            }
        }
        else{
            ForexPop = window.open('ForexDisclaimer.asp','Forex','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
        }
    }

    function CheckFoFuturePop(){
        if (FoFutureResponse=="A"){
            if (FoFuturePop.closed){
                FoFuturePop = window.open('FoFutures/EN/ftslingshot2b3/LiveMain_fr.asp?type=F', 'FoFuture', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
            }
        }
        else{
            FoFuturePop = window.open('FoFutureDisclaimer.asp','FoFuture','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
        }
    }

    function CheckFoOptionsPop() {
        if (FoOptionsResponse == "A") {
            if (FoOptionsPop.closed) {
                FoOptionsPop = window.open('FoFutures/EN/ftslingshot2b3/LiveMain_fr.asp?type=O', 'FoFuture', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
            }
        }
        else {
            FoOptionsPop = window.open('FoOptionsDisclaimer.asp','FoOptions', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
        }
    }

//  function CheckFoFuturePop_FO(){
//      FoFuturePop = window.open('FoFutures/EN/ftslingshot2b3/LiveMain_fr_FO.asp','FoFuture','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=1014,height=710,toolbar=0')
//  }

    function CheckFxBannerPop(){
        if(FxBannerPop != null){
            parent.DetailFrame.location.href = "Forex/asp/menu/100kforex_fr.asp"
        }
        else{
            parent.DetailFrame.location.href = "Forex/asp/menu/100kforex_fr.asp"
            FxBannerPop = window.open('Banner.htm','FxBanner','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0,width=600,height=300,toolbar=0')
        }
    }
    //document.body.onunload = CloseAllPop
</script>
<table width="985" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td width="10" background="images/bgsquareleft.jpg"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="940" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr><td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="64"><a href="MainMenu.asp" target="DetailFrame"><img src="POEMSBanner.gif" alt="Phillip's ON-LINE ELECTRONIC MART SYSTEM" height="54"  border="0" /></a></td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom" class="style3">

            <a href="#" onClick="TradCenPop = window.open('https://trading.poems.com.hk/Poems2/tradingcentral/index.aspx?pf=X&lang=en&id=XXXXXX','TradingCentral','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,left=0,top=0,width=680,height=480,toolbar=0')"><img src="images/Corner/EN/tradingcen.png" border=0 title="Trading Central"></a>
                            <a href="#" onClick="StockPop = window.open('http://www.poems.com.hk/stockSummary/stockSummary.asp?iKey=2755766c747a4373b375a375c05','StockAnalytics','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,left=0,top=0,width=1250,height=700,toolbar=0')"><img src="images/Corner/EN/Company.png" border=0 title="Stock Analytics "></a>&>
```

Comment: Can you upload the image highlighting the icon you wanna click as i am not able to locate the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL "https://trading.poems.com.hk/poems2/poems.asp?func=view" returns HTML code for a frameset page with not a single  tag.

Note that the Document element within the Browser object doesn't expand the underlying pages. You see the same here as you would in the browser using the "show source" function

Check the possibility of calling (one of) the framed page(s) directly

Comment: Hi How to call the framed page directly?  I tried using Firefox and click the framed info.  It gives me "https://trading.poems.com.hk/poems2/poems.asp?func=view"

Comment: But it redirects to this webpage which I don't want:  "https://trading.poems.com.hk/poems2/loginaction.asp"

Comment: so which page do you actually want to see in the browser? with VBA you can only act on a properly loaded page .... all that's happening on page loading (execution of server side or client side scripts) is beyond VBA influence